webpack.mix laravel-mix-purgecss own separate css for each landing page
Each storage directory has a folder with a landing page, which has its own css and index.html
You need to go through the directory with landing pages and process it through PurgeCSS to remove unused classes
then collect your css files for each landing page
Each landing page should have clean CSS files without unused styles, optimized, etc.
How can I make purgeCss take its own separate index.html for its style directory/landing page?
For some reason this script takes content from the last directory in the cycle
├── storage
│   └── app
│      └── landings
│            ├── landingName1
|            |  ├── css
|            |  |   ├── style.css
|            |  |   ├── other.css
|            |  ├── js
|            |  |   ├── app.js
|            |  └── index.html
│            ├── landingName2
|            |  ├── css
|            |  |   ├── style.css
|            |  |   ├── other.css
|            |  ├── js
|            |  |   ├── app.js
|            |  └── index.html
│            ├── landingName3
|            |  ├── css
|            |  |   ├── style.css
|            |  |   ├── other.css
|            |  ├── js
|            |  |   ├── app.js
|            |  └── index.html
├── public
│   └── modules
│      └── landingpage
│            ├── landingName1
|            |  ├── css
|            |  |   ├── style.css
|            |  |   ├── other.css
|            |  ├── js
|            |  |   ├── app.js
│            ├── landingName2
|            |  ├── css
|            |  |   ├── style.css
|            |  |   ├── other.css
|            |  ├── js
|            |  |   ├── app.js
│            ├── landingName3
|            |  ├── css
|            |  |   ├── style.css
|            |  |   ├── other.css
|            |  ├── js
|            |  |   ├── app.js

function mix_scss_files() {
    var landings_relative_path = "storage/app/landings/";
    var landing_paths = fs.readdirSync(landings_relative_path);

    for (var i_folder = 0; i_folder < landing_paths.length; i_folder++) {

        var landing_code = landing_paths[i_folder];
        var folder = landings_relative_path + landing_paths[i_folder];
        console.log("folder = " + folder);

        const defaultConfig = {
            content: [
                folder + '/index.html'
            ],
            defaultExtractor: (content) => content.match(/[\w-/.:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
            safelist: { standard: [/-active$/, /-enter$/, /-leave-to$/, /show$/] },
        }

        mix.js(folder +"/js/*.js", "public/modules/landingpage/"+ landing_code +"/js");

        var relative_path = folder + '/css/';

        var paths = fs.readdirSync(relative_path);

        for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
            if (paths[i].indexOf('.css') > 0 && paths[i].charAt(0) != '_') {
                var file_path = relative_path + paths[i];
                console.log(file_path);
                var path = [];
                mix.css(file_path, 'public/modules/landingpage/' + landing_code + '/css/')
                    .purgeCss({
                        content: [folder + '/index.html'],
                    });
            }
        }
    }
}

mix_scss_files();


if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}

